# Does Proguard support obfuscate package names in module-info.class

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation, module-info

I need to obfuscate a module including the exports packages declared in module-info.class.(because it will be a dependence of another module, both of them need to be obfuscated).
The proguard seems not support to handle the module-info.class.

I've tried to use this in proguard config:

```
-keep class module-info
-keepattributes Module*
```

It will keep the module-info.class remain unchanged but the real exports package names are changed after obfuscating, so here caused errors.
And without that config, the module-info.class will be removed.

How can I make the proguard also obfuscate the module-info.class?